# Remove duplicated rows based on two columns (in both directions) and sorted by a third column

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk

I'd like to remove duplicated rows from a file that look like this:

```
A   B   1e-149
A   B   7e-136
A   C   6e-147
A   C   3e-131
B   C   0.0
B   A   4e-150
B   A   1e-136
C   B   0.0
C   A   5e-148
C   A   7e-135
```

based on columns 1 and 2.

So far, I'm trying:

```
awk '!a[$1$2]++' file
```

which results in

```
A   B   1e-149
A   C   6e-147
B   C   0.0
B   A   4e-150
C   B   0.0
C   A   5e-148
```

However, I'd like to remove also those rows whose fields in columns 2 and 1 were also found. Ideally, I'd like to keep the ones with the lowest value in column three, thus resulting in:

```
B   A   4.00E-150
B   C   0
C   A   5e-148
```

Is there any way of doing this using awk and/or sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sort -g -k3 file | awk '!a[$1$2]++ && !a[$2$1]++' 
B   C   0.0
B   A   4e-150
C   A   5e-148
```

#### How it works

- `sort -g -k3 file`

  This sorts the file numerically on column 3 so that the lowest value in column 3 comes first.
- `awk '!a[$1$2]++ && !a[$2$1]++'`

  This prints the first line for which we not have previously seen the first two columns in either order.